# How to initialize UIView subclass that is load from xib? Problems with inheritance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, subclass

Hi I created UIView subclass MightyPickerView that is loaded from xib like this.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

  if (self) {
    NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MightyPickerView" owner:self options:nil];

    if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
      return nil;
    }
    if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[MightyPickerView class]]) {
      return nil;
    }
    self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Until now this works great also I used this in many previous projects without any issues. But now I want to create MightyPickerView's subclass called `TimePickerView`.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame]; // here's the problem
  if (self) {
    [self setupSizes];
  }
  return self;
}
```

When I run the app it crashes

```
[MightyPickerView setupSizes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137e53660
```

The problem is that this line `self = [super initWithFrame:frame];` return MightyPickerView instead of TimePickerView.

How should I write the MightyPickerView's initializor so that it will return subclass if it needs to.

Comment: Do not u have any outlet of TimePickerView in your MightyPickerView.xib?

Comment: TimePickerView is not the property of MightyPickerView. Its the subclass of  MightyPickerView. MightyPickerView shouldn't know anything about TimePickerView.

Comment: instead of super init. Can you try [[self alloc] init]?

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. The for the sake of simplicity I changed class names with shorter ones. And I made a typo in the error message. So I **don't** have `TimePickerView` and `setupSizes` **is** implemented inside `TimePickerView`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing makes no sense. You should not be misusing `initWithFrame` to have your view turn around and load itself from a nib. If you want to load a MightyPickerView from a nib, load it from a nib, i.e. have some *other* class say `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MightyPickerView" owner:nil options:nil];` and pull out the view. To encapsulate, use a class factory method, maybe. Do not do this sort of skanky self-substitution inside an `init`. It may have been apparently working but it was always wrong behavior and now it has come back to bite you.

Comment: Ok. It's great answer, because I didn't know for shurethat this is not a recommended way of creating views from xib. Thanks

Comment: This is true, but changing it isn't going to fix his underlying problem that loading the view from the nib is never going to be the correct subclass.

Comment: @dan sure, it will be if that's what's in the nib.

Comment: Right, but his issue is that he wants to have a subclass use the same nib as the superclass but have the view come out of the nib as an instance of the subclass.

Comment: @dan Well, if that's his issue, then he's nuts. If he thinks that's going to happen, he doesn't know what a nib is (or what an instance is, perhaps). Nibs instantiate. They are exactly like saying `[MyClass new]` (along with appropriate initialization and maybe some further configuration), in accordance with the class specified _in the nib_. You can't turn a class A into a subclass B just by calling it a subclass B. Polymorphism, don't you know. It has to _be_ a subclass B from the get-go.